# addListenerForSingleValueEvent returns dataSnapshot value null when I add query to it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a android project. There's a bug related to Firebase Database. So, I need an experienced Android developer which is much familiar whith the firebase Databse.
Bug: I am using addListenerForSingleValueEvent and when I try to get all data, It returns data and when I set query for status = ACTIVE, It returns dataSnaphot null even though the database has an ACTIVE entry. When I use addValueEventListener , it works fine.
Please help me.

```
private void getMeetingData(){

    //Constants.MEETING_STATUS = meeting_status
    //Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE = ACTIVE
    //Constants.MEETING_STATUS_INACTIVE = INACTIVE
    
    databaseReference0 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("meeting"); //is this correct
    databaseReference0.orderByChild(Constants.MEETING_STATUS).equalTo(Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //MeetingModel getAllData = null;//wait, should i run it in debug mode
            //Log.i("printMeeting",getAllData.toString());
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                MeetingModel getAllData = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MeetingModel.class);
                arrayList.add(getAllData);
                Log.d("printMeeting",getAllData.toString());
            }

            if (arrayList.isEmpty()) {

            } else {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: What type is `Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE`? You are saving the status value as `String`

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, what are the values of `Constants.MEETING_STATUS` and `Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE`? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: updated the question. Please help me

Comment: If `Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE = "ACTIVE"` is accurate, you won't get any results because your meeting status on the database is `"0"` not `"ACTIVE"`

Comment: @AlexMamo , there is no error. onDataChanged is called every time but only the dataSnapshot value is null

Comment: @samthecodingman sorry, my bad. that image is old. updated my question. see new image

Answer (score 0):

Mutating global variables is not advised because most Firebase APIs are asynchronous and they may not yet be initialized when you try to use them. As an example, this pseudo-code wouldn't work.

```java
// initialize...
getMeetingData()
// do something with arrayList now...
```

When fetching data at a location, the `DataSnapshot` that is returned will contain the data you requested **at the top level**. When performing a query at a location, the `DataSnapshot` that is returned will contain the data you requested **as its children**.

```
// A Realtime Database FETCH
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("meeting")
    .child(meetingId)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.exists()) {
                // TODO: Handle not-exists
                Log.i(TAG, "Requested meeting doesn\'t exist");
                return;
            }

            MeetingModel requestedModel = snapshot.getValue(MeetingModel.class);
            // TODO: do something with `requestedModel`
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // don't ignore this event, at least log it
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch data: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

```
// A Realtime Database QUERY
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("meeting")
    .orderByChild(Constants.MEETING_STATUS) // <-- becomes a query here
    .equalTo(Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot querySnapshot) {
            if (!querySnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                // TODO: Handle no matching data
                Log.i(TAG, "Requested query returned no results");
                return;
            }

            ArrayList<MeetingModel> matchingMeetings = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot meetingSnapshot : querySnapshot.getChildren()) {
                matchingMeetings.add(meetingSnapshot.getValue(MeetingModel.class));
            }

            // or, the simpler form:
            // GenericTypeIndicator<List<MeetingModel>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<MeetingModel>>() {};
            // List<MeetingModel> matchingMeetings = snapshot.getValue(t);

            // TODO: do something with `matchingMeetings`
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // don't ignore this event, at least log it
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch data: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

You could also use the `Task` API:

```
private Task<List<MeetingModel>> getActiveMeetings() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("meeting")
        .orderByChild(Constants.MEETING_STATUS)     // <-- becomes a query here
        .equalTo(Constants.MEETING_STATUS_ACTIVE)
        .get()                                      // <- fetch data from server
        .onSuccessTask(querySnapshot -> {           // <- mutate the returned data
            if (!querySnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                throw new DataNotFoundException();
            }

            GenericTypeIndicator<List<MeetingModel>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<MeetingModel>>() {};
            return snapshot.getValue(t);
        });
}
```

Then when you need to use it:

```
getActiveMeetings()
    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<MeetingModel> meetings = task.getResult();
            // TODO: Handle
        } else {
            Exception ex = task.getException();
            // TODO: Handle
        }
    });
```

Comment: bro, at .get() call in task api, its saying "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: @Harsh0021 Are you sure you are using the [latest dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)?

Comment: bro, i am not using bom firebase api

Comment: do i have to use it

Comment: bro, your answer is not working, tried both way